# How is the term "Born level" usually defined?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, definition

How is the term "Born level" usually defined, e.g. in talking about the $pp\to Z/\gamma^*\to e^+e^-$ cross section at Born level?

Comment: "Born level" is a linguistic mutation of "Born approximation" and "Tree-level".

Comment: Is "Born approximation" in this lingua a synonym for "Tree-level" or something in addition?